# Do domesticated animals necessarily live longer than wild animals? counterexample wanted!

Tags: zoology, senescence

Generally domesticated animals do not need to worry about their food and other predators, and they have a lower probability of getting sick.

However, it seems there is no sharp difference between the life expectancy of wild pigs and domesticated pigs. Both can survive more than ten years if they are not killed.

**Is it normal for domesticated animals to have a longer life span?** Is it necessarily so?

**Is there an example of a wild animal that statistically lives longer than its domesticated counterpart?**

Comment: generally we haven't been selecting for long life, given the amount of inbreeding many species go through and possible trade-offs (milk production in cattle for example, might be stressful for the animal) it is likely that many domesticated species live shorter than their natural counterparts. I think this question may be a) near impossible to answer (its not likely that a properly designed experiment has been conducted) and b) too broad, there's a lot of domesticated species

Comment: For a properly designed experiment you would need both sets of animals being kept in the same conditions (food space, climate, stressors, medicines), and these are likely to be further from what one group is adapted to than the other, and given the complexity, requirement of large sample sizes, cost of the experiment & how little there is to be gained from doing such an experiment, it is unlikely to have been done.

Comment: I think this will either encourage opinion based answers, or bring to light a paper that looked into this in great detail. Either way, my money is on a pug surviving longer in a Parisian apartment rather than the Chinese wilderness!

Comment: Yeah this question will potentially draw many isolated answers. For example, indoor-cats are indeed known to grow older than cats that spend a lot of time outdoors (e.g. feral cats) because the latter contract more disease and get killed by cars, or get baited by nasty folks etc.

Comment: guys, can we just make this question simple?  e.g.  wild birds vs. pet birds ?  I just need a counterexample which statistically speaking lives longer than its domesticated counterpart .

Comment: @questionhang - that's exactly what we are trying to analyze for you. It is *up to you* to make this question answerable. If you think you know exactly what you want, why isn't it in the question? The concluding question is simply too broad. I vote to close until edited.

Comment: @aliceD  OK, I have revised the question.

Comment: I think the heart of the matter is in the "not killed". A domestic animal which slows down due to age often will be cared for by its humans. The same animal in the wild is almost certainly food for another animal.

Comment: @jamesqf  On the other hand, there are domesticated animals which do not like their man-made environments and crowded people who stares at them.

Comment: @questionhang Consider we raise pigs to eat them, longevity is not a priority, in fact breeding them to get larger faster probably would shorten their normal lifespans. Consider comparing species bred for a purpose other than consumption.